# How to detect wlan network is out of range

Tags: networking, wifi, linux

Is there any suggestion how to detect the wlan network is out of range ?

I've successfully made my device to connect access points and connected other access points also. I'm using the /etc/network/interfaces/wlan0 configuration file to connect different encrypted network.

For example : I connected to a network1 then I moved away from the network line of sight in that case I want to show network coverage out of range instead of failure to connect. Is there any way to do that in linux ?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I know I'm going to get smacked for this... but.... gotta.....    Uh... if you can't connect (failure to connect), then you're 'out of range'.   Pretty much just semantics at this point.  Both mean the same thing... no network.  You choose what error / response to give a user.

Comment: You probably will able to work out whether the signal strength is diminishing (try `iwconfig` or something), however once it has got out of range it probably will just say it is not connected to anything.

Comment: I don't authenticate the network login credentials. If it is correct its connects. Actually I wrote a small shell script $iwconfig wlan0 | grep 'signal'. Question I need to make this script run all the time, doesn't consume more battery ? I don’t want to run shell script in background which will consume more cpu cycle.